# Double json serialization in client

Tags: c#, json

I am serializing objects in cloud server in the web role:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;    
string returnJsonMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(returnMessage);
```

On the client side:

```
BaseResponseDeviceMessage retVal = null;
        var req = HttpWebRequest.Create(@reqString);
        req.Method = requestMethod;
        req.ContentLength = 0;
        req.ContentType = @"application/json";

        string jsonResp = "";
        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                jsonResp = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

            string t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(jsonResp);
            retVal = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(t);

        }
```

You can see that in order to get my message back, I need to DeSerialize twice.
Why? how can this problem be solved? 
Thank you all, and a good day.

Comment: Seems you return a string in the server instead of returning your real object. Most probably, you don't need `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` on server side.

Comment: How do you return the string from the sever? Your code only show that you serialize your object which doesn't help us much with understanding your problem.